# Ramdajs keyBy equivalent of lodash

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array that I want to transform into an object. For example:

```
const arr = [{id: 1, key: ''}, {id: 2, key: ''}];
```

I want the result to be:

```
const object = { 1: {id: 1, key: ''}, 2: { id: 2, key: ''}}
```

With `lodash` I can use the `keyBy` function, but I am working with [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) and did not find this functionality there.

Comment: I think you want [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) perhaps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve this with very basic reduce function.

```
function keyBy(entities, id = "id") {
    return entities.reduce((acc, entity) => {
      acc[entity[id]] = entity;
      return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone still finds this via search, the correct answer is [`indexBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy), added in mid-2016.

```
const list = [
  { id: "xyz", title: "A" },
  { id: "abc", title: "B" },
];
R.indexBy(R.prop("id"), list);
//=> {abc: {id: 'abc', title: 'B'}, xyz: {id: 'xyz', title: 'A'}}
```

See Also:

- [Github: Ramda Wiki "What Ramda Function Should I Use?"](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/What-Function-Should-I-Use)
- [Github: Ramda Issue #931 - "sister to groupBy"](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/931)